# In R, why does is.numeric(NaN) print "TRUE"?

Tags: r, nan, numeric

NaN` means "Not a Number". However I found out that the result of

```
is.numeric(NaN)
```

is

```
[1] "TRUE"
```

Anybody know why? I think the result should be `FALSE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Not a Number" does not really mean it is not a number. It is a special coding of a floating-point number. See **ANSI/IEEE 754 floating-point standard**, or simply the Wikipedia page for NaN.

***This is a universal standard for all computing languages and R's handling is no exception.***

In R, `typeof(NaN)` gives "double", and `mode(NaN)` gives "numeric". Now if you read `?is.numeric`, you see that `is.numeric(x)` returns `TRUE` if `x` has mode "numeric" and is not a factor.

The IEEE standard defines three special floating-point numbers, `Inf`, `-Inf` and `NaN`.

The first two have a clear mathematical meaning: positive infinite and negative infinite. Although they are not part of real number, they are **well-defined limit**. For example, `1 / 0` is `Inf`.

So what does `NaN` mean? Precisely it is **not well-defined real number**. Simple cases are

```
0 / 0  # can be either Inf or -Inf
sqrt(-1)  # not well-defined on real number set
Inf - Inf  # can not be decided, can be 0, Inf or -Inf
```

In numerical computing, if the result can not be written in regular real number, or `Inf` or `-Inf`, it is expressed as `NaN`. In this regard, arithmetics between any floating-point numbers becomes completely representable. `NaN` is quite informative in this regard, it means "something has gone wrong".

---

Note that unlike `NA` which has various types (`NA_real_`, `NA_integer_`, etc), `NaN` has only one type for floating-point numbers. Any logical, character, integer values are not floating-point numbers hence can not be `NaN`. The definition of NA is not a universal standard and R has its own.